# jquery uncaught reference error for the javascript function

Tags: jquery

Hi i am getting an error like Uncaught ReferenceError: downloadCSV is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclic. Please help me out from this error..I am trying to get the json and download that json to excel..Is that code correct.

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>
<a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ILFc2zlUXHI&key=""&part=snippet,statistics', function(data) {
       var stockData = {"name": "data.items[0].snippet.categoryId" , "id" : "data.items[0].snippet.channelId" , "an" : "data.items[0].snippet.title"};

})

function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
        var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

        data = args.data || null;
        if (data == null || !data.length) {
            return null;
        }

        columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
        lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

        keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

        result = '';
        result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
        result += lineDelimiter;

        data.forEach(function(item) {
            ctr = 0;
            keys.forEach(function(key) {
                if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                result += item[key];
                ctr++;
            });
            result += lineDelimiter;
        });

        return result;
    }

    function downloadCSV(args) {

        var data, filename, link;

        var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
            data: stockData
        });
        if (csv == null) return;

        filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

        if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
            csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
        }
        data = encodeURI(csv);

        link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', data);
        link.setAttribute('download', filename);
        link.click();
    }
    });
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting the same error

Comment: It is inside the document.ready function only

Comment: I am trying to access the json response and saving that data to excel file..I am getting the uncaught reference error.If there are any errors please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the downloadCSV function is in side the document.ready() , thus making it unaccessible.

2 options

1. move the function out of the document ready
2. Setup a listener on the link inside the document ready that calls the function.

i.e.

```
$('body').on('click','#linkid', function(e){
downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });
});
```

where you give the link the id of linkid

Comment: If i put the function outside the document ready function i am getting the following error...Uncaught ReferenceError: stockData is not defined
    at downloadCSV (abhi.html:16)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick..

Comment: I kept the two function before document.ready function.One more new error came like   Uncaught ReferenceError: stockData is not defined
    at downloadCSV (abhi.html:55)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM183 abhi.html:7)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>  
    <html>  
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>
    <a href='#' onclick='downloadCSV({ filename: "stock-data.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {


   });    

    function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }

            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;

            data.forEach(function(item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                    result += item[key];
                    ctr++;
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });

            return result;
        }

        function downloadCSV(args) {

            var stockData = [];
            var data, filename, link;

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ILFc2zlUXHI&key=""&part=snippet,statistics', function(data) {
                    stockData.push({"name": data.items[0].snippet.categoryId , "id" : data.items[0].snippet.channelId , "an" : data.items[0].snippet.title});

                    var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                        data: stockData
                    });
                    if (csv == null) return;

                    filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

                    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                        csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
                    }
                    data = encodeURI(csv);

                    link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.setAttribute('href', data);
                    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                    link.click();

            });

        }

    </script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: stockData is not defined
    at downloadCSV (abhi.html:55)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM183 abhi.html:7)

Comment: I got this error after putting all the functions outside the document.ready Uncaught ReferenceError: stockData is not defined
    at downloadCSV (abhi.html:55)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM183 abhi.html:7)

Comment: put  **var stockData** before document.ready and reassign it inside getJSON

Comment: I did not got what you are telling.can you please rechange the code and send me

Comment: GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ILFc2zlUXHI&key=""&part=snippet,statistics 400 ().Now i am getting this error

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: Now it is working but i am not able to download the csv file..so if i click the download csv button no file is getting downloaded

Comment: i am getting this following error.....Failed to create temp file 18 : It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.

Comment: test it with less data or static data and see if it works.

Comment: i have tested the code myself its working, it generates csv and downloads it.

i tested with static data 
var stockData = [{"name": "sad" , "id" : "1" , "an" : "sad"}];

stock data should be an array.

Comment: it is working with static data but its not working with dynamic data

Comment: i mean like this : var stockData = [{"name": "data.items[0].snippet.categoryId" , "id" : "data.items[0].snippet.channelId" , "an" : "data.items[0].snippet.title"}];

Comment: var stockData = [{"name": data.items[0].snippet.categoryId , "id" : data.items[0].snippet.channelId , "an" : data.items[0].snippet.title}]
try this

Comment: it is telling that the data is not defined

Comment: is that the correct way to pass the dynamic array.Actually i am calling the json below and how can we call the array on the top

Comment: i hv updated the code thats a better way of doing it, hv a look

Comment: Hi how to create n number of arrays?var stockData = [{"name": data.items[0].snippet.categoryId , "id" : data.items[0].snippet.channelId , "an" : data.items[0].snippet.title}] ..In that we are specifying data.items[0] right? how can we define n number of arrays and loop it?

Comment: console.log(data.items[4].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay); so if i put like this i am getting only one comment from the fourth array.Like that i have n number of arrays..so how can i do that.